# Skip bash while loop if function inside fails a condition

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, continue

I have a while loop that reads a file line by line and pass the line to multiple functions or nested functions inside the loop. if one of the function finds something wrong I want the while loop to skip that iteration and go to the next one.

I did search a lot and tried different things but using  'continue to skip the while loop was the only solution everywhere but it doesn't seem to be helping. I am not sure where or how to look for something like this. Is there a solution or a different approach to solving this issue? Thanks for any help.

```
   function2(){
   "if some condition that uses $test_name fails, skip the while loop"
  }

  function3(){
   do something
  }

  main_function (){
    do something to $test_name
    function2 $test_name
    function3 $test_name
  }

  while true read -r line; do
    if [[ ! "${line}" =~ ^# && ! -z "${line}" ]]; then
       test_name=$line
        main_function  $test_name 
    fi
 done < $OS_LIST
```

Comment: Make sure your functions all return valid success (0) or failure (nonzero) codes. Have main_function execute each as `func $arg || return 1` or some such so that it doesn't keep running tests after one fails. Then call main as `main_function $arg || continue`.

Comment: I guess you answered the question I asked Andre, thanks a lot for your clear explanation, I will it a tr.

Comment: I am not sure why this question was downvoted, can someone please help me out?

Comment: Let me know if you want me to submit a full-blown example.

Comment: Dunno about the downvote. If I had to guess I'd say read [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) explanation of why you should give brief but clear evidence of the research you have done.

Comment: @PaulHodges Thanks a lot Paul, you answer was exactly what I was looking for and it did work for me. Really apreciate it.

Comment: @PaulHodges Thanks for the comment Paul. I did search a lot but 'using continue' was the only solution I could find which didnt help. I wasnt sure how to even start with this or dont know where to look for, thats why I end up posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write the functions so that they return a nonzero status if they fail, zero if they succeed (actually, you should be doing this anyway as a general good practice). Something like this:

```
function2() {
    if some condition that uses $test_name fails; then
        echo "test condition failed in function2" >&2    # Error messages should be sent to stderr
        return 1
    fi
    # Code here will only be executed if the test succeeded
    do_something || return 1
    # Code here will only be executed if the test AND do_something both succeeded
    do_something_optional    # No error check here means it'll continue even if this fails
    do_something_else || {
        echo "do_something_else failed in function2" >&2
        return 1
    }
    return 0    # This is actually optional. By default it'll return the status
                # of the last command in the function, which must've succeeded
}
```

Note that you can mix styles here (`if` vs `||` vs whatever) as the situation warrants. In general, use the style that's clearest, since your biggest enemy is confusion about what the code's doing.

Then, in the main function, you can check each sub-function's exit status and return early if any of them fail:

```
main_function (){
    do something to "$test_name" || return 1    # BTW, you should double-quote variable references
    function2 "$test_name" || return 2    # optional: you can use different statuses for different problems
    function3 "$test_name"  || return 1
}
```

If you need to skip the end of the main loop, that's where you'd use `continue`:

```
while true read -r line; do
    if [[ ! "${line}" =~ ^# && ! -z "${line}" ]]; then
        test_name=$line
        main_function "$test_name" || continue
        echo "Finished processing: $line" >&2    # Non-error status messages also go to stderr
    fi
done < "$OS_LIST"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation@Gordon Davisson. I just implemented the same in my code with the help of @Paul Hodges. Appreciate your detailed explanation, it will definitely help other people.

Answer (score 2):

My take on it -

```
$: cat failout
#! /bin/env bash

OS_LIST=os_list

func1() {
  if [[ -z "$1" ]]
  then echo "ERROR - Empty string!"
       return 1
  fi
}

func2() {
  grep -q foo <<< "$1" || { echo "ERROR - no 'foo'!"; return 1; }
}

func3() { echo "all good here"; }

mainfunc() {
  func1 "$1" || return 1
  func2 "$1" || return 1
  func3 "$1" || return 1
}

while read -r line
do echo "before:[$line]"
   mainfunc "$line" || { echo test failed; continue; }
   echo all tests passed.
done < <( grep -Ev '^[[:space:]]*(#.*)*$' $OS_LIST )
```

Note that the loop eliminates comments and empty lines with a grep before the read.

The input file, os_list, with line numbering on

```
$: vi os_list
  1
  2
  3
  4   # shan't
  5
  6 foo bar other stuff
  7
  8 just foo
  9
 10 footed...
 11
 12 bar, without any required string!
 13
 14 more foo
 15
 16
```

For the record, some of those empty lines do have blanks, some don't.
The results:

```
$: failout
before:[foo bar other stuff]
all good here
all tests passed.
before:[just foo]
all good here
all tests passed.
before:[footed...]
all good here
all tests passed.
before:[bar, without any required string!]
ERROR - no 'foo'!
test failed
before:[more foo]
all good here
all tests passed.
```

Hope that helps. It could certainly be better.
Questions welcome.

Comment: I just submitted an answer that covers some things I thought weren't well covered yet... and I see you've beat me to it. Oh, well, have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in function 2 if the test fail :

```
return 1
```

In the main function :

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   function3 $test_name
else
   return
fi
```

Hope it can help

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andre Gelinas. I have another question, If I have more functions after functions3 and if I want to do the same with func3, do I need to add your if condition before going for function4 and so on?

Comment: Same, {return n} gives you the capacity to send an error code. 0 is the default and usually means that everything is alright. But by setting specific error code like that you can even be more granular on each function and react accordingly. Like if function 2 doesn't work and return let say error code 2, don't do function 3 but function 6 instead of skipping by example.